# Facebook discount system using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application i want to give discount to user(s) for sharing my product(s) on facebook.I din't get any online solutions for this problem. Can anyone suggest some idea how do i implement this.If you have any online resources plese suggest.

Comment: do you just want to know if they share your link, or only if people click on them?

Comment: I want to know if my link is shared and then apply a discount.

Comment: Your question got answer try to search for it.. 
If your script is using FB api to share something at FB ,at each user share there is created object and its id is returned to your PHP api as respond. At FB and you may get information using that ID, who has created this object.

Comment: can you describe the flow from the user's sharing the app to actually purchasing? will the user be authenticating your app with fb at all? how do you plan on identifying who the user is? (do they already have an account on your site? are you using fb as the login for your site? Do you plan on randomly generating/sending out a discount code that can be used anonymousy?)